# Perl: How do I find a parent folder of a known subfolder?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and I'm having some trouble getting a parent folder of a known sub-folder(s).
So I have a list of subfolders, let's say A, B, C, D, etc.
I know they are all scattered around in folders labeled (for eg.), 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

So it can be like this:
1/A
1/B
2/C
3/D
3/E
etc.

I just want to iterate through each folder and find it's direct parent directory.  Any ideas?

EDIT:  Changed PERL to Perl :P

Comment: I think there is the same question and its answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318769/perl-get-parent-folder-name .

Comment: The name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL". It's not an acronym; it's an intentional misspelling of "Pearl".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

my @matches =
   File::Find::Rule
      ->name(qw( A B C D ))
      ->directory
      ->in('.');
```

---

It handles deep dir just fine.

```
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l

$ touch a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/file

$ mkdir -p 0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9

$ touch 0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/file

$ perl -MFile::Find::Rule -E'say for File::Find::Rule->in(".")'
.
a
a/b
a/b/c
a/b/c/d
a/b/c/d/e
a/b/c/d/e/f
a/b/c/d/e/f/g
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/file
0
0/1
0/1/2
0/1/2/3
0/1/2/3/4
0/1/2/3/4/5
0/1/2/3/4/5/6
0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7
0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8
0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9
0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/file
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  Just as an FYI, As I said before I'm new to Perl so I'm not sure if this has to do with the version of Perl I have installed on my computer, but I had to change ->dir to ->directory to make it work.  Thanks for the quick answer ikegami!

Comment: My mistake. Fixed.

Comment: Just as a note to other users planning on using the File::Find::Rule library, this will most likely to fail (as it did in my case) if your directories contain many nested folders.  File::Find::Rule seems to have difficulty traversing back to the directory I specified in ->in($path) flag.  In my case, I happened to have roughly 10+ nested folders in the path i provided.  Otherwise, it's a solid solution.  It worked perfectly in my test program, just not in the actual scenario I was hoping for..  :(

Comment: I think you misdiagnosed the issue. Are you sure it's not hitting some kind of path length limit (240 in Windows)? As you can see by the code I added to my answer, it can handle deep dirs without problem.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that path length limit on windows (I'm a mac user)...  it looks like it might've hit that character limit, but from the logs, it seems like File::Find::Rule is using 'cd ../../.. etc" to traverse back.  I'm positive this won't trigger the character limit violation.  But you're right, it does make sense that that's the reason why it's failing at long paths. I'll have to look into it further.  Regardless, if this is the case, Windows users will have trouble using this Library in the scenario I specified above.

Comment: ug, didn't realize it used File::Find's default chdir behaviour, which makes it susceptible to permission issues and possibly others. You could try specifying `->extras({ no_chdir => 1 })`